# VS Code intellisence not working after migrating project to another Repo

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've started programming on a c# compiler a while ago, and since then switched from azure devops to github in my normal programming routine.

So when I picked up work again, I started committing to azure again, and found it really inconvenient to just have one project to another devops soulution so I decided to import this repo to github as well.

This was a day ago.

The previous days I've worked a lot in code and intellisense was working nicely, just until I imported the program to github, deleted the project folder on my pc and pulled the repo off of Github. I now this probably is not the most convenient way of doing this, but that's what I did.

Now intellisense completely stopped working.

Normaly ctrl+. should give me a huge list of things I could do, but it always says that there are no code actions available. Even the red squiggles don't appear until I try to run the project which makes it very hard to write code effectively as I often have loose ands I thought I fixed already.

So far I have tried reinstalling intellisense, the C# language extension and "re-pulling" the entire project, if that is an adequate term.
Of course I tried turning on and off my computer as well, but this mysteriously did not solve my problem.

My question now is how I can fix this, if there is a way to reset intellisense in a way or if it's even possible to "destroy Intellisense for a project" as this seems pretty dumb. The solution probaly is easy and right in front of my eyes but I'm not able to see it.

Of course I looked at similar questions on Stack overflow but the suggested tips did not work either.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I've edited the question because I forgot to summarize my problem into a proper question